# Where on Stack Exchange can I ask questions relating to Facebook?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange, facebook

I have a question relating to features of Facebook - namely how to rename a group that was set up via a Facebook page.

Is there any part of the Stack Exchange that covers these types of questions?

Comment: For that kind of [tag:site-recommendation] questions you're probably better off at [SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions). Stack overflow is about programming related questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's nothing wrong with asking this question here- It's just as on-topic here as it would be there. This is a question about the _Stack Exchange network_ after all.

Comment: @Kendra Well, OKI. I said _probably better_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour):

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> - Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

— WebApps [On-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)